# 10x10 Fillomino

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

[Interactive solving website](https://puzz.link/p?fillomino/10/10/565p9i8h5h6g5h4g2i6h43r8hch3cg7g6i3l6n7k7i7g67ic)

For help/rules on solving, please look at the website's "help" section, which lists fillomino rules. Please use the website to solve the puzzle unless you are unable to. Post a screenshot of the finished puzzle in your answer.[image: 10x10 Fillomino]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deductions of the form "this region must take this square or it would be cut off" get this far:

> [image]

Next, make sure not to create regions that are too big:

> The 6 region can't connect to the clue in R5C4, and that leads to another chain of deductions.
>  [image]

Continue extending...

> with the 7 and 8 in the lower left, and make sure not to cut off the 8 in the top right with the 4.
>  [image]

And finally...

> We have 28 cells left over. 6+7+12 = 25, so there's no room for another big region -- the 12s *must* connect. And sure enough, there is only one way to do that, giving the solution:
>  [image]